# Windows 11 TortoiseGit menu not showing after Register context menu clicked

Tags: contextmenu, tortoisegit, windows-11

I have try to googling method/ways that can make the TortoiseGit menu show in the main context menu in Windows 11 but still not showing.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xNpB.png)

1. Custom Context Menu for Windows 11 - For this I can only add one of the function in TortoiseGit to the context menu for example push.
2. Windows 11 Context Menu in Tortoise Git - For this, I try many times but not working at all. After I press the "Register Context Menu" button, it show Package Registered, but nothing happen to the Win 11 Context menu. [Package Register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtQJU.png)

But the menu still not showing. [TortoiseGit not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYaX3.gif)

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

I wanted to show the TortoiseGit menu in the main context menu in Win11 like the image [Show like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amAce.png) by not changing the context menu to Win10.

Thanks in advance!!